# tkinter scrolledtext scroll from left to right

Tags: tkinter, horizontal-scrolling

in a calculation application, I am printing text into a `Tkinter scolledtext` widget. if the text gets longer than the widget, the text is fitted from top to bottom (more rows). but what I want is to keep the same rows and scroll to the right. how can I change scrolling direction from vertical to horizontal?

```
group1 = LabelFrame(root, padx=5, pady=5)
group1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=100, padx=10, pady=10)

self.display_abf = tk.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(group1, width= 130, height=40, bg="lightgrey")
self.display_abf.grid(row=1, columnspan=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `wrap` attribute to the string `"none"` to turn off wrapping of the text.

The `ScrolledText` makes adding a horizontal scrollbar complicated, so I recommend using a standard `Text` widget.

Example:

```
self.display_abf = tk.Text(group1, width= 130, height=40, bg="lightgrey", wrap="none")
xsb = tk.Scrollbar(group1, orient="horizontal", command=self.display_abf.xview)
self.display_abf.configure(xscrollcommand=xsb.set)
xsb.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=100)
```